# Visual Studio Code Django debugging breakpoints not triggered on Views and Templates

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I am facing a debugging issue with VsCode where it's failing to trigger any type of breakpoints (standard or log), but specifically on View calls and Templates. Breakpoints in other parts of the Django project structure work correctly. For example in this code sample:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/home.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

A breakpoint on `template_name = "home/home.html"` will be triggered successfully when the Class is constructed. However a breakpoint on `return render(request, self.template_name, {})` will never trigger (I would expect it to trigger when the user navigates to the URL this class renders).

A few things I have already tried:

1. Disable all other VsCode extensions aside from Python, Jupiter, and Pylance
2. Revert to a 4-month-old (I'll explain why 4 months below) version of VsCode, the Python extension, PyLance, and Django
3. Creating a function-based view of the above (which also doesn't trigger the breakpoint)
4. Create a brand new Django project (been able to reproduce this on a brand new project, and two other existing projects)

The 4-month-old timeline was because the last time I was working with Django and debugging Views was about 4 months ago so figured I would try those versions. I am fairly certain this worked last time I attempted this but I may be mistaken.

For reference, I'm using the standard Django launch config. I tried changing some options like `--noreload` and `stopOnEntry` but that didn't affect the outcome. Copying the config file below for reference:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Furthermore, setting breakpoints in the Templates do not trigger either and setting a breakpoint in a function called by the get method does not trigger (anything post View call basically).

Everything I can see from the documentation says this should work, and I thought it used to. What am I missing this time around or has something changed?

Comment: For reference, I just tried to re-create this bug on a fresh install of Windows in a VM and it works correctly there with the same setup and Python/Django versions. Perhaps there is something else on my PC that could be interfering with the debugger?

Comment: -Is the defined "get()" method called in the code? In VS Code, we need the "Python" extension, which provides Django functions. For the use of Django in VS Code, you could refer to: [Django Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah it is, it's called whenever the user navigates to that URL (the URL loads and the Django log reports the method was called and rendered). Thank you for the link as well, I've read through that about a dozen times yesterday trying to figure this out haha.

One other thing I noticed, is the debugger doesn't report any threads on my main PC. It just shows the subprocess that Django calls but not its threads it spawns (where it does on the VM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. A couple of weeks ago I installed gevent (`pip install gevent`) for a project. Doing so added `GEVENT_SUPPORT=True` to my environment variables. When enabled, this prevents VsCode from debugging the Python standard library's threading module. Changing this variable to `False` fixed it for me (of course I am not using gevent at this point).

More information can be found on this issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/189

Answer (score 0):

"django": true
in my code over here when i run the code but the issue is in the terminal saying that NameError on true. Also its not debugging the breakpoint.
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Python: Current File",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"justMyCode": true,
"django": true
},

```
    {
        "name": "Stock_manage",
        "python": "/Users/akchhabhyashakya/Desktop/python/New stock/Stock_manage/my-venv/python3",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/Users/akchhabhyashakya/Desktop/python/New stock/Stock_manage/manage.py",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "args": [
            "runserver"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).